# Parameters to pass auto.key to draw symbols in the key

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to create an xyplot with the key on the right hand side and symbols as well as lines (which have to be given in the key as well). I'm running the following code:

```
xyplot(value ~ variable | conditionCol1 + conditionCol2,
              data = rt, groups = groupingCol, type = "o", pch = 1:6,
              auto.key = list(space = "right", pch = 1:6),
              xlab = "Instance Size",
              ylab = "Execution Time")
```

The returned graph is correct and has both lines and different symbols for the different groups, however all symbols in the key are coming up as circles...

Comment: can you please post a reproducible example, eg part of your data?

Comment: I can't post part of my data, because its under data protection contract, but here is a generic one:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing `pch` as its own argument, pass it as a component of the `par.settings` argument. That should ensure that the graph and the key use the same parameters.

The trick is determining which component of `par.settings` to use. In this case, it would be `superpose.symbol`, since `panel.superpose` is the panel function used when you use the `group` argument, and you want to change the symbol that is plotted. So:

```
xyplot(value ~ variable | conditionCol1 + conditionCol2,
              data = rt, groups = groupingCol, type = "o",
              par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 1:6)),
              auto.key = list(space = "right"),
              xlab = "Instance Size",
              ylab = "Execution Time")
```

And using a reproducible dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
xyplot(cty ~ hwy | cyl + fl,
              data = mpg, groups = year, type = "o",
              par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 1:6)),
              auto.key = list(space = "right"),
              xlab = "Instance Size",
              ylab = "Execution Time")
```